# Why doesn't defaults read` work for obtaining ShadowHashData key in user.plist?

Tags: terminal, password, user-account, open-directory

I've read how to obtain the user's password hash on OSX using `sudo defaults read /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/user.plist ShadowHashData`.

However, after giving Terminal "Full Disk Access" on macOS Mojave, I get the following error:

```
The domain/default pair of (/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/user.plist, ShadowHashData) does not exist.
```

However, the ShadowHashData key can be read by `plutil` and `dscl`, so why don't `defaults` work?

Edit:

`dscl` (works for obtaining user's hash):

```
nlykkei-mbp:~ nlykkei$ sudo dscl . -read /Users/nlykkei dsAttrTypeNative:ShadowHashData
dsAttrTypeNative:ShadowHashData:
 62706c69 73743030 d2010203 ...
```

`defaults` (doesn't work for obtaining user's hash):

```
sudo defaults read /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/nlykkei ShadowHashData
2019-08-07 09:16:32.697 defaults[1123:33825] 
The domain/default pair of (/var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/nlykkei, ShadowHashData) does not exist
```

`whoami` (user's identity):

```
nlykkei-mbp:~ nlykkei$ whoami
nlykkei
nlykkei-mbp:~ nlykkei$ id
uid=501(nlykkei) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),502(access_bpf),12(everyone),61(localaccounts),79(_appserverusr),80(admin),81(_appserveradm),98(_lpadmin),33(_appstore),100(_lpoperator),204(_developer),250(_analyticsusers),395(com.apple.access_ftp),398(com.apple.access_screensharing),399(com.apple.access_ssh),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1)
```

`uname` (OS version):

```
nlykkei-mbp:~ nlykkei$ uname -a
Darwin nlykkei-mbp 18.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.6.0: Thu Apr 25 23:16:27 PDT 2019; root:xnu-4903.261.4~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

`defaults` (works without domain argument):

```
nlykkei-mbp:~ nlykkei$ sudo defaults read | head -n 10
{
    "Apple Global Domain" =     {
        AKLastIDMSEnvironment = 0;
        AppleKeyboardUIMode = 3;
        "com.apple.sound.beep.flash" = 0;
    };
    bluetoothaudiod =     {
    };
    "com.apple.AppleMultitouchMouse" =     {
        MouseButtonDivision = 55;
 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

The ‘read’ verb for defaults takes a domain, not a filename, therefore the `.plist` suffix should be omitted.

```
sudo defaults read /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/user ShadowHashData
```

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Shuzheng What error do you get? Did you replace `user` with your correct username?

Comment: I get the same error as above. Yes, I replaced the username.

Comment: I've added much more elaborate information. Can you spot now, why `defaults` doesn't work for obtaining hash data?

Comment: any idea ...? :)